# C++ Visual Studio release build is not working (OpenCV 4.5.2)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Now, I tried to build release mode from C++ source code with OpenCV.

This source code is built on debug mode, but it is not built on release mode.

The below images are my OpenCV library setting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please give me your help

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenCVServer, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>StreamServer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV_InputArray@1@@Z)
1>StreamServer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::read(class cv::_OutputArray const &)" (?read@VideoCapture@cv@@UEAA_NAEBV_OutputArray@2@@Z)
1>C:\workspace\OpenCVStream\OpenCVServer\x64\Release\OpenCVServer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "OpenCVServer.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please provide texts or screenshots of errors that you get when trying to build Release.

Comment: I got the below error messages.

Comment: The error might be happening because you provided `...d.lib` of OpenCV to your linker. `d` suffix in library file name means that it is debug library. All .lib files are usually shipped as two files, one for release (without `d`) and one for debug (with `d`). Try to find release .lib and place it into your linker configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solve the issue.

Comment: If comment above correctly solved your problem then don't forget to accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67411256/941531) and/or UpVote it. Accepting an answer can be done left-handside at the beginning of answer. There is a checkmark for accapting it, and upper-arrow for UpVoting.

Comment: what I found was that opencv4.x installs in usr/include under opencv4/ but references opencv2 in pretty much every example, which also appears to be the case in the second image shown. perhaps change the path, or copy the libraries elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is most probably happening because you provided OpenCV library named `...d.lib` to your release linker configuration.

`d` suffix in library file name means that it is debug library. All .lib files are usually shipped as two files, one for release (without `d`) and one for debug (with `d`).

Try to find release .lib and place it into your linker configuration.